# Using fixed width on a flex item and adjusting the other items accordingly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to build input groups where multiple inputs can be placed next to each other. By default, they will take up equal widths, and I am using flexbox for the whole thing.

Here is what the code looks like:

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group > .input {
  position: relative;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 0%;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  min-width: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.width-50 {
  width: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="State">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="School">
</div>
<br />
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="input width-50" type="text" placeholder="Title">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Full name">
</div>
```

The only issue I have is that I want to be able to change the widths of the inputs using utility classes. For example, the first input on the second row has the `width: 50px` property. However this does not work for some reason. On top of this, **the second input on the second row** should ideally stretch out and take up the rest of the width when the first input gets smaller. How can I fix this issue? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stripped your example to have a better focus on the solution. The code below does what you want. I use `width: 50px` to make the input smaller, and  `flex-grow: 0` to prevent it from growing larger than that. I use `flex-grow: 1` on the other inputs to make sure they fill out the remaining space.

```css
.input-group {
  display: flex;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.width-50 {
  width: 50px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="State">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="School">
</div>
<br />
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="input width-50" type="text" placeholder="Title">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Full name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just make sure the class `.input.width-50` will not grow or shrink and updated the flex-basis to the desired width.

```
    .input.width-50 {
      flex: 0 0 50px;
    }
```

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group > .input {
  position: relative;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 0%;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  min-width: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.input.width-50 {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="State">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="School">
</div>
<br />
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="input width-50 " type="text" placeholder="Title">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Full name">
</div>
```